# NodeJS My SQL query with Chain promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I have 3 function and i want to call this function to step by step, for example when i will call firs function and get result, i have to call second function and pass parameter returned from first call. after i will finish second call i have to call third function and pass parameter returned from second function.

#1:

```
getCategory = function (branch_id) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var categoryData;
    var query = 'SELECT id,name,price,currency FROM category  where branch_id=?';
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query(query, [branch_id], function (error, row, fields) {
            if (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            } else {
                connection.release();
                deferred.resolve(row);
            }
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise; }
```

#2:

```
getRoom = function (branch_id, categoryID) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var roomData;
    var roomSql = 'SELECT id,room_no,name,price,currency FROM room  where branch_id=? and category_id=?';
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query(roomSql, [branch_id, categoryID], function (error, row, fields) {
            if (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            } else {
                connection.release();
                deferred.resolve(row);
            }
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

#3:

```
getReservationL = function (room_id, start_date, end_date) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var reservationData;
    var reservationSql = 'SELECT d.id,d.create_date,d.update_date,d.room_id,d.status_id,d.start_date,d.end_date, ' +
        ' s.name as status_name,a.id as reservation_id,a.person_no as person_no, p.first_name,p.last_name,p.email ' +
        ' FROM reservation_detail d ' +
        ' inner join reservation_status s on d.status_id=s.id ' +
        ' inner join reservation a on d.reservation_id=a.id ' +
        ' inner join person p on a.person_no=p.personal_no ' +
        ' where d.room_id=? and d.start_date >? and d.start_date<?';
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query(reservationSql, [room_id, start_date, end_date], function (error, row, fields) {
            if (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            } else {
                connection.release();
                deferred.resolve(row);
            }
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I need something like this:

```
data = getCategory()
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   data[i].room = getRoom(data[i].id);
   for(j=0;j<data[i].room[j].length;j++){
      data[i].room[j].reservation = getReservationL(data[i].room[j].id);
   }
}
```

How to implement this pseudo code in NodeJS using promise or callback. I would prefer to use promise.

**UPDATE#1**
I have data like this after second iteration

```
[
  {
    "id": 64,
    "name": "VIP",
    "price": 116.5,
    "currency": "USD",
    "room": [
      {
        "id": 44,
        "room_no": "101",
        "name": "A",
        "price": 100,
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      {
        "id": 274,
        "room_no": "505",
        "name": "a",
        "price": 1,
        "c\r\nurrency": "GEL"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 74,
    "name": "SUPER VIP",
    "price": 110,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "room": [
      {
        "id": 54,
        "room_no": "102",
        "name": "A",
        "price": 100,
        "currency": "GEL"
      },
      {
        "id": 284,
        "room_no": "606",
        "name": "a",
        "price": 1,
        "currency": "GEL"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 84,
    "name": "DOUBLE",
    "price": 110,
    "currency": "GEL",
    "room": [
      {
        "id": 204,
        "room_no": "103",
        "name": "b",
        "price": 120,
        "currency": "GEL"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I wand to iterate over each category's each room's.

```
     getCategory(branch_id).then(firstRecords => {
        let promises = firstRecords.map(function (record) {
            return getRoom(branch_id, record.id)
                .then(roomData => {
                    var res = Object.assign({}, record, { room: roomData });
                    return res;
                })
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
//HERE i have data that is placed above.
    }).then(secondRecords => {
        let promises = secondRecords.map(function (category) {
            return category.room;
        }).map(function (rooms) {
            console.log('SECOND', rooms);
            return rooms;
        }).map(function (reservation) {
            console.log('THERD', reservation);
            return reservation;
        })
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }).then(reservation => {
        console.log("Reservation", reservation);
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve a promise using `.then` and can chain `then` to resolve multiple promises in a synchronous fashion.

Maybe this will solve your use case.

```
getCategory()
.then( firstRecords => {

  console.log('firstRecords: ', firstRecords);

  let promises = firstRecords.map( record => getRoom(record) );
  return Promise.all(promises);
})
.then( secondRecords => {

  console.log('secondRecords: ', secondRecords);

  let promises = secondRecords.map( record => getReservationL(record) );
  return Promise.all(promises);
})
.then( thirdRecords => {

  console.log('thirdRecords: ', thirdRecords);
})
```

**Reference:** [Promise then chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining)

> The then method returns a Promise which allows for method chaining.
>
> If the function passed as handler to then returns a Promise, an equivalent Promise will be exposed to the subsequent then in the method chain

**Refrence:** [Promise all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

```
Promise.all([ { key: 1 }, Promise.resolve(3), 1, true ])
.then( results => {
    results[0]; // { key: 1 }
    results[1]; // 3
    results[2]; // 1
    results[3]; // true
})
```

## Update #1

`Promise.all` only accept an array of promise and not object with promises on the key.

```
# wrong
Promise.all([
    { key: Promise.resolve(1) },
    { key: Promise.resolve(2) },
    { key: Promise.resolve(3) },
])

# right
Promise.all([ 
    Promise.resolve(1), 
    Promise.resolve(2), 
    Promise.resolve(3) 
])
```

you could do something like this to achieve the what you have mentioned in comments.

```
getCategory(branch_id)
.then( firstRecords => {

  console.log('firstRecords: ', firstRecords);

  let promises = firstRecords.map( record => {
    return getRoom(branch_id, record.id)
    .then( roomData => Object.assign({}, record, { room : roomData }) )
  });
  
  return Promise.all(promises)
  
})
```

If you want to append the data of the first and second promise, then resolve the promises there only to access the data of both in one place.

## Update #2

As you mentioned in comments, this code might help you.

```
getCategory(branch_id)
.then( categories => {

  let roomPromises = categories.map( category => {
    return getRoom(branch_id, category.id)
    .then( rooms => Object.assign({}, category, { rooms }) )
  });

  return Promise.all(roomPromises)

})
.then( category_rooms => {

  let finalPromise = category_rooms.map( category => {
    
    let reservationPromises = category.rooms.map( room => {
      return getReservationL(room.id, start_date, end_date)
      .then( reservations => Object.assign({}, room, { reservations }) )
    })

    return Promise.all(reservationPromises)
    .then( room_reservations => {
      return Object.assign({}, category, { rooms: room_reservations })
    });
  })
  
  return Promise.all(finalPromise)
})
.then( data => console.log(data) )
```

Comment: I have The following code:    getCategory(branch_id).then(firstRecords => {
        console.log('firstRecords: ', firstRecords);
        //record => getRoom(branch_id, record.id)
        let promises = firstRecords.map(function (record) {
            var roomData = getRoom(branch_id, record.id); 
            record.room = roomData;
            return record;
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }) i'm getting room: { state: 'pending' } } any idea?

Comment: This method get promises getRoom(branch_id, record.id); and may be i have  { state: 'pending' } . How to resolve this?

Comment: after second iteration im getting the following object: [
  {
    "id": 64,
    "name": "VIP",
    "price": 116.5,
    "currency": "USD",
    "room": [
      {
        "id": 44,
        "room_no": "101",
        "name": "A",
        "price": 100,
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      {
        "id": 274,
        "room_no": "505",
        "name": "a",
        "price": 1,
        "c\r\nurrency": "GEL"
      }
    ]
  },...} now i wand to iterate each categorys each rooms

Comment: getCategory(branch_id).then(firstRecords => {
 let promises = firstRecords.map(function (record) {
return getRoom(branch_id, record.id)
  .then(roomData => {
                    var res = Object.assign({}, record, { room: roomData });
                    roomData.map(function () {
 return getReservationL(roomData.id, start_date, end_date).then(reservationData => {
console.log("ReservationData", reservationData);
 return Object.assign({}, record, { room: roomData });
   })
  })
 })
}); is it right code to iterate ower categorys rooms ?
        return Promise.all(promises);
    })

Comment: please update your question, with an update heading. I can't possibly understand the code in comments.

Comment: @ZurabKatsitadze please try this [gist code](https://gist.github.com/raghavgarg1257/b01f9d1392da94b6aac5ddbce56aa4d3), I am not fully certain if it will work. Do share your results with us here.

Comment: Can you see my comment once again ? sorry for my less knowledge in promises. I'm new in node js and my sql.

Comment: @ZurabKatsitadze, it has been some time since you last commented, I have [commented in the gist](https://gist.github.com/raghavgarg1257/b01f9d1392da94b6aac5ddbce56aa4d3#gistcomment-2185286) but it seems you haven't seen it. I have updated my answer with my gist code. If it works for you please accept the answer, else please comment either here or on my gist.

Comment: Can you see result one more time.

Comment: have replied on the gist, please take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much you really help me.

Answer (score 0):

As your logic contains lot of `loop` statements for data selection and transformation, you need to refactor it into something like:

```
getCategory(brandId)
    .then(addRoomData)
    .then(addReservationData)
    .then(handleFinalData)
    .catch(handleError);
```

For `addRoomData` and `addReservationData` functions, you may need to use [**Promise.all() combined with `.forEach()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31426920/2576485).

If you want to write your code in a more readable way, consider using [**`async / await`**](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9?gi=3141eab5f4be).

Answer (score -1):

I think the more optimize way is to use **async.waterfall** function of **async** module.
https://caolan.github.io/async

```
async.waterfall([
function(callback) {
    getSomething(options, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback(new Error("failed getting something:" + err.message));
            // we should return here
        }
        // since we did not return, this callback still will be called and
        // `processData` will be called twice
        callback(null, result);
    });
},
function(data, callback){
  //do something
}
], function(err,results){
  //get final results
});
```