# How to Promise in loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

```js
    var arr = ["node.js", "Java", "C#"];
var newArr = [];

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                newArr.push(arr[i])
                resolve(newArr);
            }, 1000);
        }

});

promise
        .then(result => {
             alert(result);
         }
);
```

Now it alerts data after first loop. How to display data from async operation with promises, after it passes whole loop?

Desired behavior: Add data to newArr in async mode, and display it after loop ends.

Comment: Well you can only resolve it once..... So you would have to wait until all the timeouts are done....

Comment: ```Promise.all``` is what ye' seek

Comment: @epascarello can you show me how?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @epascarello no examples with loops...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return many Promises in a loop and wait for them all to do other stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426740/how-to-return-many-promises-in-a-loop-and-wait-for-them-all-to-do-other-stuff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have multiple promises with [promise all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
const myPromises = [];
for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
  myPromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("done", i);
        resolve(i)
      } , i*500);
  })); 
}

Promise.all(myPromises).then(values => { 
  console.log("All: ", values)
});
```