# Returning a single resolve() from a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I wrote the below code snippet:

```
var data = require('./readFile.js');
const argv = require('./index.js');
const colors = require('colors');
const rp = require('request-promise').defaults({ encoding: null });
const memeImage = argv.name;
const path = './json/meme.json';

var myData;

data.readFile(path)
.then(function (value) {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(value);

    const options = {
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
    }
    jsonData.forEach(element => {
        if(element.title == memeImage) {
            rp.get(element.image, options)
            .then(function(response){
                if(response.statusCode == 200) {
                    myData = Buffer.from(response.body).toString('base64');
                    myData.replace('myData:image/png;base64,', '');
                    console.log(myData);

                    resolve(myData);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Error in retrieving image.  Status code: ', response.statusCode);
                    reject('Error in retrieving image.');
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log('Error in downloading the image via request()');
                reject('Error in downloading the image via request()');
            });
        }
    });
})
.then(function(myData) {
    console.log(myData);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    //Error in reading the file
    console.log(err);
})

module.exports=myData;
```

Here, function `readFile()` imported from a different file (`readFile.js`) returned a promise.  `readFile.js` is as below:

```
var myData, obj, found=false;

function readFile(path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(!fs.existsSync(path)) {
            console.log('Will throw error now!');
            reject("memes.json file does not exist");
        }
        else {
            //File exists
            console.log('File found');
            var data = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
            resolve(data);
        }
    })
}

module.exports.readFile = readFile;
```

Now in the topmost code snippet, my aim is to read a file (that maps a title to a URL) using the `readFile.js` file and then download the image at the corresponding URL.  Once this match is found (if clause above), the promise should be resolved and returned to a new module.

What happens right now is, I get the following output:

> node ./lib/getImage.js -n title -t topText -b bottomText 
> File found 
> undefined 
> <... image ... as a base64 string> 
> Error in downloading the image via request() 
> Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: reject is not defined ...

My question is, answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426740/how-to-return-many-promises-in-a-loop-and-wait-for-them-all-to-do-other-stuff) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328932/javascript-es6-promise-for-loop/40329190) all talk about returning multiple promises from a loop.  In my case, I just want to return a single promise resolve (depending upon the match) and just stop.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't just blindly call `resolve()` and `reject()` inside a `.then()` handler.  Those functions are ONLY defined in a manually created promise so they don't exist in your context.

If you want to set the resolved value in `.then()` handler, then just `return` that value.  If you want to reject inside a `.then()` handler, then either `throw someErr` or `return` a rejected promise.

If you're inside a `.forEach()` callback and you want to stop further processing and set the resolved value of the parent promise, you can't.  You're inside a callback function so you can't directly `return` from the outer function and `.forEach()` has no way of stopping its iteration.  Instead, use a regular `for` loop and then you can just `return value` to both end the `for` loop iteration and to establish the resolved value of your promise chain.  A regular `for` loop gives you significantly more control over the program flow than a `.forEach()` loop.

FYI, `Unhandled rejection ReferenceError:` is caused by creating an exception inside your `.catch()` by attempting to call an non-existing `reject()` function.  Remove that.  If you want to log and keep the promise rejected, then `throw`.

And, then if you use `rp.get()` inside a `for` loop, you will either need to use it with `await` or `Promise.all()` with it in order to know when everything is done.

Comment: Oh, but I do have a `.catch()` corresponding to _console.log('Error in downloading the image via request()');_ which is related to `rp.get()`, no?

Comment: And, could you please elaborate _A regular for loop gives you significantly more control over the program flow than a .forEach() loop_?

Comment: @J.Doe - Yeah, you do I didn't see that because of your different coding style.  But the error happens because you're creating another error in your `.catch()` with `reject('Error in downloading the image via request()');` and there's no `.catch()` after that to catch that new error.  Of course, you don't want another `.catch()` - just remove the reject.

Comment: @J.Doe - With a regular `for` loop, you can `return` or `break` to stop the iteration.  With `.forEach()` there's no way to stop the iteration.  With a `for` loop inside a `.then()` handler, you can use `return someValue` to finish the `.then()` handler and set the resolved value of the promise chain and stop the loop.  Inside a `.forEach()` callback, you can't do either one of those because returning from inside the `.forEach()` callback just finishes that iteration and the `.forEach()` loop just keep chugging along.

Comment: @J.Doe - Frankly with `for/of` and block scope in modern Javascript, there's rarely ever a reason I use `.forEach()` any more.  It's just extra overhead and coding complication with little benefit.

Comment: Great, thanks, @jfriend00.  I appreciate your help!