# asyncronous callbacks inside for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

```js
var a = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
var op = [];

cb = (callback) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    gtts.savetos3(`${a[i]}.mp3`, a[i], 'ta', function(url) {
      console.log(url['Location']);
      op.push(url['Location']);
    });
  }
  callback()
}

cb(() => {
   console.log(op);
})
```

In the above code the *gtts.savetos3* is an **asynchronous function**.It takes significance amount of time to complete the execution for every element in array.Due to asynchronous feature I cannot print the complete array of url in **op** array as it prints an empty array.

*gtts.savetos3* function calls the given callback with correct url so that i can print the output using `console.log` but when comes to looping i got messed up.

**My question is**

1. How to make the callback function called only after the execution of
   the all array elements get processed by the *gtts.savetos3* function.
2. can we achieve the solution for above problem without **Promise.all** or without **Promise** with the help of using only **callbacks**.

> Thanks in Advance ...!

Comment: you can use `await`

Comment: Why don't you want to use `Promise.all`? It *is* by far the most elegant solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426740/how-to-return-many-promises-in-a-loop-and-wait-for-them-all-to-do-other-stuff There are workarounds, sure, but I wouldn't want to recommend them

Comment: what is `gtts.savetos3` is it `aws-sdk`'s method?

Comment: It is customized method which uses aws-sdk.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  could you provide the simple example which has the similar pattern using promises.All ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426740/how-to-return-many-promises-in-a-loop-and-wait-for-them-all-to-do-other-stuff

Answer (score 2):

> You can keep a counter and increase it inside the methods's callback,
>   call your `done` callback only when the counter reaches the length of
>   the array.

```
cb = (done) => {
    let counter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        gtts.savetos3(`${a[i]}.mp3`, a[i], 'ta', function (url) {
            console.log(url['Location']);
            op.push(url['Location']);
            ++counter;
            if (counter == a.length) {
              done();
            }
        });
    }
}

cb(() => {
    console.log(op);
})
```

This is just a way to solve the problem without `Promises` or any third party module but not the elegant or correct way.

> If you want to stick to the callback and are ok to use third-party module have a look on
>   [Async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) `waterfall method`.
>
> If you are using `aws-sdk`'s `s3 put object`, then sdk already provides a
>   promisified methods as well, you can simply append your method with
>   `.promise` to get the same.
>
> To solve the problem with promises just change your wrapper into an
>   async function.

```
async savetos3(...parametres) {
    //Some implementation
    let res = await S3.putObject(....params).promise();
    //Some implementation
}

cb = Promise.all(a.map(name => savetos3(`${name}.mp3`, name , 'ta')));

cb.then(() => {
    console.log(op);
})
```

Comment: I think the If condition should in the callback to the savetos3 function call but not outside of for loop.

Comment: Due to  asynchronous function call the **op** array is not update properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```js
const a = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
const op = [];

const saveToS3 = name => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gtts.savetos3(`${name}.mp3`, name, 'ta', function (url) {
        console.log(url['Location']);
        resolve(url)
    });
})

Promise.all(a.map(item => saveToS3(item))).then(() => {
    console.log(op)
})
```

Comment: Working like charm . Could you explain why the ```callback()``` inside the **async** function is called only after all **await** syntax .

Comment: That is just async/await. In async function, await blocks the function until the awaited promise is resolved or rejected.

Comment: @AZ_ please provide the pure promisified snippet.

Comment: Please check again. Of course, we can use async function instead of Promise.

Comment: @TopW3 will it blocks the complete code execution below the await condition? or only just particular condition?

Comment: @ThuraiSelvaraj It blocks the current function(async)

Comment: @TopW3 Is there any other method which we can obtain the above solution? If exists kindly list it .