# React with conditional promises chain and wait for them all before send dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm new to react. I have a user list that fetched once when the component mounts.
and before the results dispatched to the reducer, it needs to loop inside the userlist and get user fullname/title from another endpoint, then add a new property to userlist object.
I cant figure out how to wait for all promises (getUserById() function) to finish before calling a dispatch. I tried the solution here, but failed:
[How to return many Promises and wait for them all before doing other stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426740/how-to-return-many-promises-and-wait-for-them-all-before-doing-other-stuff)

code below just to illustrate what I want:

```
  const {
    listUsers,
    fetchUserData
  } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const getUserById = async (userId) => {
    return sp.web.siteUsers.getById(userId).get().then(user => user.Title);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    sp.web.lists.getById("8C271450-D3F9-489C-B4FC-9C7470594466").items.get()
    .then(userLists => {
      userLists = userLists.map(list => {
        if (list.Person_x0020_ResponsibleId) {
          getUserById(list.Person_x0020_ResponsibleId).then(username => {
            list['Person_Responsible'] = username;  // -> fetch user fullname and title
          })
        } else {  // -> if id is null
          list['Person_Responsible'] = '-';
        }
        return list
      });

      fetchListSuccess(userLists);  // -> dispatch result to reducer
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). First you need an array of promises from your second API calls. Then we'll give this array to `Promise.all`, and it will wait until they all resolve.

I've rewritten using `async/await` syntax. It works the same as using `.then` with the promises, but when you're working with a promise chain that's this complex it's easier to follow with `async/await`.

```
useEffect(async () => {
  const userLists = await sp.web.lists.getById('8C271450-D3F9-489C-B4FC-9C7470594466').items.get();
  const promises = userLists.map(async (list) => {
    if (list.Person_x0020_ResponsibleId) {
      const username = await getUserById(list.Person_x0020_ResponsibleId);
      list.Person_Responsible = username; // -> fetch user fullname and title
    } else { // -> if id is null
      list.Person_Responsible = '-';
    }
    return list;
  });
  await Promise.all(promises);
  fetchListSuccess(userLists); // -> dispatch result to reducer
}, []);
```

A few notes:

- You don't really need to reassign `userLists` in the map, because you're just adding a property to existing objects. This will happen without the map.
- Now the map is being used to return an array of promises for your second API calls. This is used by the `Promise.all` to wait until all those promises resolve.

Comment: wow it works, thanks a lot! I never really understood the mechanism of Promise, now I understand more about it.