# How to return the values in the order of the data passed to a promise in a loop?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, tokenize, kuromoji

To learn about fetch, promise, and other js stuff I'm trying to write a small script that suggests words to learn (base on its difficulty) from a given Japanese text.

It utilizes a Japanese parser called [Kuromojin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kuromojin).

What a parser like Kuromojin does is that it tokenizes a phrase into words.

e.g. data: "日本語が上手ですね!" →　tokenied words: [{surface_form: 日本語}, {surface_form: が}, {surface_form: 上手}, {surface_form: です}, {surface_form: ね}, {surface_form: !}]

The script first tokenizes words from data, then fetch each tokenized word's corresponding JLPT level by using a Japanese dict's API (jisho.org)

The app.js file:

```js
import {  tokenize,  getTokenizer} from "kuromojin";
import {  parseIntoJisho} from "./parseintojisho.js";

const text = "日本語が上手ですね！";
let tokenSet = new Set();

getTokenizer().then(tokenizer => {});

tokenize(text).then(results => { // the result is an array of objects

  results.forEach((token) => {
    tokenSet.add(token.surface_form);
  })

  console.log("======Begin to find JLPT level for below items======");
  tokenSet.forEach((item) => {   
    console.log(item);

    parseIntoJisho(item); // will throw a console log of whichever item's corresponding data is resolved, regardless of item order here, right?
  });
})
```

The parseintojisho.js file:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

/* @param data is string */


export function parseIntoJisho(data) {
  fetch(encodeURI(`https://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword=${data}`))
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(jsondata => {
      let JLPTvalueArray = jsondata.data[0].jlpt;

      if (JLPTvalueArray.length) {
        let jlptLevel = JLPTvalueArray.flatMap(str => str.match(/\d+/));
        const max = Math.max(...jlptLevel);
        if (max >= 3) {
          console.log(data + " is of JLPT level N3 or above.")
        } else console.log(data + " is of JLPT level N1 or N2.");
      } else console.log(data + " has no JLPT value.")
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log("No data for " + data);
    })
}
```

The script works but instead of showing the JLPT level corresponding to each tokenized word in order, it shows randomly. I guess whichever corresponding data is resolved first will appear in the console log?

What I've found out is that `Promise.All()` [may solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426740/how-to-return-many-promises-and-wait-for-them-all-before-doing-other-stuff), but I couldn't find out a way to implement it correctly.

Is there a way to put the fetched JLPT levels in the order of the tokenized items that were passed into `parseIntoJisho(item);`?

```
$ node app.js
======Begin to find JLPT level for below items======
日本語
が
上手
です
ね
！

です has no JLPT value. // should be "日本語 has no JLPT value." here instead
No data for ！ // should be "が has no JLPT value." here instead
上手 is of JLPT level N3 or above. 
日本語 has no JLPT value. // should be "です has no JLPT value." here instead
ね is of JLPT level N3 or above.
が has no JLPT value. // should be "No data for ！" here instead
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map` instead of `forEach`, then log each item of the resulting array *after* all asynchronous requests are done.

To pass along the original string into the asynchronous results function, use `Promise.all` on both the `parseIntoJisho` and the original data.

```
Promise.all([...tokenSet].map(parseIntoJisho))
  .then((results) => {
    for (const [data, result] of results) {
      if (!result) continue; // there was an error
      if (result.length) {
        const jlptLevel = result.flatMap(str => str.match(/\d+/));
        const max = Math.max(...jlptLevel);
        if (max >= 3) {
          console.log(data + " is of JLPT level N3 or above.")
        } else console.log(data + " is of JLPT level N1 or N2.");
      } else console.log(data + " has no JLPT value.")
    }
  });
```

```
const parseIntoJisho = data => Promise.all([
  data,
  fetch(encodeURI(`https://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword=${data}`))
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(jsondata => jsondata.data[0].jlpt)
    .catch(err => null)
]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I use `const tokenSetArray = [...tokenSet];` in order to use the `.map` for tokenSet. However, I've tried some ways but couldn't work your answer out. Particular with `const parseIntoJisho = data =>` I get the error data is undefined. Could you elaborate a bit more in your answer (particularly how to embed them into my code) ? Thank you!

Comment: If after `parseIntoJisho = data =>` the data is undefined, then it looks like you aren't using the code in the answer that calls it with `tokenSet.map(parseIntoJisho)` - that'll pass the argument along. Unless the Set literally contains `undefined` values, of course. After adding the tokens to the Set, replace all the code inside `tokenize(text).then` with the code in my answer

Comment: Thanks.  I will try it asap and reply back. One small thing is that tokenSet is a set, so I should parse them into array first before using .map right? Cause in your answer I see you use .map with a tokenSet, which is a set and have no .map method as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, right, definitely, turn it into an array first.

Comment: hi, hope that you are still there xD I've tried to do exactly as you said but an error showed up: "Cannot access 'parseIntoJisho' before initialization. I've tried some ways like put the `const parseIntoJisho` above the Promise.all() but got another error (data is undefined). My code is here: https:// paste.ofcode.org/Vg7RbGX5ZGNga3VmjHf5RS

Comment: Variables declared with `const` or `let` can't be referenced before the line that initializes them runs. I'd move the `parseIntoJisho` out of the function onto an outer level. Or you can declare `parseIntoJisho` before the `Promise.all` part

Comment: Hi, I've tried to move the `const parseIntoJisho = data =>` out of the function, even out of the bracket to initialize it but always get the error property `jlpt` is undefined. I guess it's because when we do  `const parseIntoJisho = data =>` the initial data that is used to pass into fetch is always the value of `const parseIntoJisho ` which is undefined. Could you please take another look at your code to verify its integrity? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The `const parseIntoJisho` is the function, it should never be undefined. The `data` argument should always be defined too if the elements of the Set are all defined, `[...tokenSet].map(parseIntoJisho)` will pass each item of the Set as the first argument to the function. What exactly is the error message you're getting? Even if `.jlpt` were undefined, accessing it alone shouldn't throw an error

Comment: I got `TypeError: cannot read property 'jlpt' of undefined` then below is `UnhandledPromisingRejectionWarning: Referenced Error: data is not defined`
my code: https:// paste.ofcode.org/38upuYnXsSek2AmrFmtbBPM

Comment: Use the `result` variable name instead, since that's the loop parameter

Comment: hi, thanks. The original variable `data` is used to log the value of the tokenSet. If using `result` then it will log the jlpt value. `.then((results)` will only pass results which contain the jlpt value, how can I tap into the original tokenized data to show it ? e.g `result + " is of JLPT level N3 or above."` === `jlpt-n5 is of level N3 or above`. I want `日本語 is of level N3 or above`. Is there a way to pass which data is mapped in map(parseIntoJisho) (so I could tap into that data instead of result)?

Comment: Looks like you'll need another `Promise.all`