# How do I know that the loop callback is complete?

Tags: javascript

```js
allDoc.map(function(stage){
      for(let key of stage.layerItem){
          //key.toImage is a library, so it only supports callback.
          key.toImage({
              callback(img) {
                  addPhoto(key.attrs)
              }
          });
      }
})

// Run when addPhoto is done
console.log("done")

async function addPhoto(params){
  const stored = await s3.upload(params).promise()
  return stored.Location
}
```

When the addPhoto function is completed, how do I proceed to the next code?

Answer (score 0):

First [wrap the `toImage` function in one that returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) then [use `Promise.all`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426740/how-to-return-many-promises-and-wait-for-them-all-before-doing-other-stuff) to wait for them all to settle.

(Community Wiki because this is close to being a duplicate question but has two distinct steps each of which has their own duplicate).

Comment: i'm a beginner so I don't know, can you tell me how to use it? 
What I've done is this:

Comment: let promise = new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
                                    key.toImage({
                                        callback(img) {
                                            resolve(addPhoto(key.attrs))
                                        }
                                    });
                                })
                                await Promise.all(promise).then(async result => {
                                    console.log("result",result)
                                })

Answer (score -1):

One of the solutions I found for waiting `.map()` to be complete, is putting a `Promise.all()`.

Your code should look like this:

```js
const promisse = allDoc.map(function(stage, index){
    // Your loop
})

await Promise.all(promisse);

console.log('done');
```

Keep in mind that if your `allDoc.map` is inside another function, the upper function must be `async`.

Comment: The function passed to allDoc.map doesn't return a promise so that won't work.