# .then after promise is execute before promise is finished

Tags: javascript

I'm new in javascript and struggling in asynchronous concept of javascript.
In the following code the function `handler.flexCarouselReply`, which should wait for the `resultArr`, is executed before promise is finished.

```js
new Promise((resolve) => {
    const resultArr = checkRedeemList.map((redeemPath) => {
      const couponCode = redeemPath.id;
      redeemPath.get().then((redeemInfo) => {
        if (redeemInfo) {
          console.log(`checking ${couponCode}`);
          const redeemData = redeemInfo.data();
          const createDate = redeemData.CreatedDate;
          const expireDate = redeemData.ExpiredDate;
          console.log(`${couponCode} createDate ${createDate} expireDate ${expireDate}`);
          const isUsed = redeemData.UsedDate;
          if (!isUsed) {
            console.log(`${couponCode} is active`);
            const reward = redeemData.Reward;
            reward.get().then((rewardInfo) => {
              const rewardData = rewardInfo.data();
              const title = rewardData.Title;
              const backgroundColor = rewardData.ButtonColor;
              const imgUrl = rewardData.TransparentImageUrl;
              return {
                "type": "bubble",
                "direction": "ltr",
                "header": {
                  "type": "box",
                  "layout": "vertical",
                  "contents": [{
                      "type": "box",
                      "layout": "baseline",
                      "contents": [{
                          "type": "text",
                          "text": "รหัสรางวัล:",
                          "flex": 2,
                          "contents": [],
                        },
                        {
                          "type": "text",
                          "text": `${couponCode}`,
                          "flex": 4,
                          "contents": [],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "box",
                      "layout": "baseline",
                      "contents": [{
                          "type": "text",
                          "text": "สถานะ:",
                          "flex": 2,
                          "contents": [],
                        },
                        {
                          "type": "text",
                          "text": "ใช้งานได้",
                          "weight": "bold",
                          "color": "#4FEA0BFF",
                          "flex": 4,
                          "contents": [],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
                "hero": {
                  "type": "image",
                  "url": `${imgUrl}`,
                  "size": "full",
                  "aspectRatio": "1.51:1",
                  "aspectMode": "fit",
                  "backgroundColor": `${backgroundColor}`,
                },
                "body": {
                  "type": "box",
                  "layout": "vertical",
                  "contents": [{
                      "type": "box",
                      "layout": "baseline",
                      "contents": [{
                          "type": "text",
                          "text": "ชื่อรางวัล:",
                          "flex": 2,
                          "contents": [],
                        },
                        {
                          "type": "text",
                          "text": `${title}`,
                          "size": "xs",
                          "flex": 4,
                          "wrap": true,
                          "contents": [],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "box",
                      "layout": "baseline",
                      "contents": [{
                          "type": "text",
                          "text": "วันที่แลก:",
                          "flex": 2,
                          "contents": [],
                        },
                        {
                          "type": "text",
                          "text": `${createDate}`,
                          "size": "xs",
                          "flex": 4,
                          "wrap": true,
                          "contents": [],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "box",
                      "layout": "baseline",
                      "contents": [{
                          "type": "text",
                          "text": "วันหมดอายุ:",
                          "flex": 2,
                          "contents": [],
                        },
                        {
                          "type": "text",
                          "text": `${expireDate}`,
                          "size": "xs",
                          "flex": 4,
                          "wrap": true,
                          "contents": [],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              };
            });
          } else {
            // not show
            util.log("test", `the ${couponCode} is expired or already used`);
          }
        } else {
          //  redeem in fo already been deleted
          util.log("test", `the ${couponCode} already been deleted`);
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        //  error get redeem info
        util.log("test", `Error getting redeem information ${error}`);
      });
    });
    resolve(resultArr);
  }).then((resultArr) => {
      console.log(`resultArr ${resultArr}`);
      handler.flexCarouselReply(req, res, replyToken, CONST.ChannelEnum.BOT, resultArr);
  };
```

How can I manage to ordered the step of this execution.

Comment: you `resolve(resultArr);` before the asynchronous code inside `checkRedeemList.map((redeemPath) => {` has a chance to execute

Comment: You're calling `resolve(resultArr)` without waiting for the promises in it to settle. To wait for a bunch of promises to settle, you can use `Promise.all` (or `Promise.allSettled` depending on your use case). See the [linked question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426740/) for details. But also, when you already have a promise/promises (which you do from `redeemPath.get()`), [there's no need for `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/); use the promise/promises you have. Here's an example: https://pastebin.com/Su7nBTZV