# JS smart way to handle multiple asyncs

Tags: javascript, async-await

I wonder how to await the outcome of multiple async functions properly:

```
async function call1() {
    let result = await $.ajax({url: `api/call1`});
    data1 = result;
};

async function call2() {
    let result = await $.ajax({url: `api/call2`});
    data2 = result;
};
```

My approach:

```
let somevar = function () {
    call1().then( var1 => {
        call2().then( var2 => {

            console.log("call1", data1, "call2", data2);
        });
    });
};
```

This is how I tried it, and I am sure this is not the way how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return many Promises and wait for them all before doing other stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31426740/218196). Don't use shared variables. With `Promise.all` you can  do `Promise.all([$.ajax(...), $.ajax(...)]).then(([data1, data2]) => ...)`

Comment: @xtlc Felix refers to those globals `data1` and `data2`. Do not use them. Just have the functions `return` the result value, and then `console.log("call1", var1, "call2", var2);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise.all()

```js
const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([call1(), call2()]);
```