# TypeScript - wait for the function to complete until executing the next function

Tags: typescript, async-await

I have two functions: doAsyncStuff and doNextStep.
How can I secure doNextStep to be executed only after doAsyncStuff is finished?

I tried something like that but it didn't help: `doAsyncStuff().then(_ => doNextStep());`

```
async function doAsyncStuff() {
    if (vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders) {
        vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders.forEach(async (e) => {
            for (const [name, type] of await vscode.workspace.fs.readDirectory(e.uri)) {
                console.log(name);
            }
        });
    
    }
    return true;
}

function doNextStep() {
    console.log('next step');
}
```

Comment: Where you you execute `doNextStep`?

Comment: You should be using actual `foreach` not the function. Callback caller doesn't await the callback function.

Comment: Using `forEach` here will not allow the promises to resolve before that function returns. You should replace it with `map`, and wrap the result in a `Promise.all` which you can `await` to ensure that all those finish before executing the next step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return many Promises and wait for them all before doing other stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426740/how-to-return-many-promises-and-wait-for-them-all-before-doing-other-stuff)

Comment: await Promise.all(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders.map(async ... await)) will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. I went through them, tried different approaches, and in the end @hotcakedev 's solution works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your replies, the solution of hotcakedev works out of the box.
*Promise.all(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders.map(async ... await))*

And this is how it looks like (resulting scenario uses async recursive function 'readFolders', which is also working well):

```
        await Promise.all(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders.map(async x => {


            for (const [name, type] of await vscode.workspace.fs.readDirectory(x.uri)) {
               console.log(name);
            }
            // await readFolders(x.uri,x.uri.path);



        }));



        console.log('fin');
```

Comment: Glad that helped!