# Getting wrong data stored in state variable when the correct data is being console logged

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to store data in my state. When I console log the data I get the correct data. When I store it in my state and console log it, I keep getting "c" in my console. Why is C being stored in my state when there is no sign of "c" in my entire code

This keeps giving me C in my console.

```
const getIds = async () => {
    Axios.get(
      "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"
    ).then((response) =>
      response.data.map((res) => setCoinIds(...coinIds, res.id))
    );
    console.log(coinIds);
  };
```

This logs the correct data:

```
const getIds = async () => {
    Axios.get(
      "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"
    ).then((response) => response.data.map((res) => console.log(res.id)));
  };
```

Why is the data not stored in my state?

Comment: Side note: You're [misusing `map`](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/) *(post on my blog)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on:

1. You're looping over the received resources, but reusing the same `coinIds` every time; that will lose previous updates and only keep the last one.
2. You're missing the `[]` in `setCoinIds(...coinIds, res.id)`, so what you're doing is spreading out the value of `coinIds` as **discrete arguments** to `setCoinIds`. But `setCoinIds` will ignore all but the first argument.
3. Separately from #1, you could well also be running into the "stale closure" problem. Your code is setting state based on existing state (by using `coinIds` when setting the new value). You're also doing asynchronous work, which means that `coinIds` may well be out of date by the time you do that. Instead, use the callback form of `setCoinIds`.

Separately, the `console.log` at the end fo `getId` will show you the value prior to the Axios callback, so it's not giving you any useful information and could be confusing.

Finally, there's no reason for `getIds` to be `async`. You're not using `await` within it, you're using `.then` instead. (It also needs a `.catch`.)

Fixing those things:

```
const getIds = () => {
    Axios.get(
        "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"
    )
    .then((response) => {
        setCoinIds(coinIds => [...coinIds, ...response.data.map(res => res.id)])
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ...report/handle error...
    });
};
```

That does this:

- Loops through `response.data` getting an array of the `id` values of each of the data objects.
- Makes only a single call to `setCoinIds`, filling in all the new values at once.
- Uses `[]` so we're passing a single array.
- Uses the callback form of `setCoinIds` so that it's using the most up-to-date state value.

Comment: That worked great! I had another question if you don't mind answering.
`const getData = async () => {
    Axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${ids}').then(
      (response) => console.log("data: " + response)
    );
  };`

I need to iterate over the coinIds to put each ID in this API call. How would I do that?

Comment: @HusnainMehmood - Glad that helped. I just noticed a couple of other things and updated the answer. Re looping through those IDs, see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426740/how-to-return-many-promises-in-a-loop-and-wait-for-them-all-to-do-other-stuff). Happy coding!