# Uploading many files simultaneously to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload many files simultaneously to my bucket. I don't want to upload them one by one; these are temporary files, so once they are all uploaded, I completely delete the folder they were in, which seems better in terms of performance. How can I do this with GCS?

This is my current code with a loop deleting all the files one by one after uploading them

```
for (const fileName of files) {
            const fsPath = `${outputFolderPath}/${fileName}`;
            const videoFullPath = `${uuid}/${fileName}`;

            const fileUploaded = await CloudStorage.op().uploadFile(
              `./${fsPath}`,
              file.mimetype,
              videoFullPath,
              bucket,
            );

            fs.unlinkSync(fsPath);
          }

          fs.rmdirSync(outputFolderPath);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return many Promises and wait for them all before doing other stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426740/how-to-return-many-promises-and-wait-for-them-all-before-doing-other-stuff)

Comment: Don't use await with the promises returned by the uploads.  Instead, collect all the promises into an array and use `Promise.all()` to wait for them all to complete before moving on to deleting the files.

Comment: @DougStevenson Already had done that, and now I confirm I was right, thank you very much

Comment: @PatoP, please post your comment as an answer so that it would be helpful to other community members with similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A promise is made for each file in the temp directory, and in the end, a `Promise.all` is used to wait for all of them to be resolved, meaning, all files are uploaded

```
const promises = files.map(async fileName => {
  const fsPath = `${outputFolderPath}/${fileName}`;
  const videoFullPath = `${uuid}/${fileName}`;

  const fileUploaded = await CloudStorage.op().uploadFile(
    `./${fsPath}`,
    file.mimetype,
    videoFullPath,
    bucket,
  );

  fs.unlinkSync(fsPath);
});

await Promise.all(promises);

fs.rmdirSync(outputFolderPath);
```